# How does a loader allocate/deallocate static data from a dynamic module

Tags: c++, linker, loader, mex, elf

Question for the linker gurus out there.  I have been working with mex files in Matlab and have been getting awful lot of unexplained crashes so I want to dig a bit deeper.

Can you explain to me how static data is allocated (deallocated) in a process' virtual memory space when a dynamic module is being loaded (unloaded)?

I assume this takes place in the `_init()` and `_fini()` functions.  However does the BSS segment get assigned a chunk of memory in the heap space, along with other dynamic memory allocations?

What about global data in a dynamic module?  Would there be possibility of symbol name clashes with the primary executable?

Thanks for shedding light on these issues.   If I have to choose a platform I would like to hear from the ELF experts since I do most of my development on Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can you explain to me how static data is allocated (deallocated) in a process' virtual memory space when a dynamic module is being loaded (unloaded)?

That part is easy: every `ELF` file has `PT_LOAD` segments, which you can see in the output from `readelf -Wl foo.so`. When loading the shared object, each of these segments is `mmap`ed into address space, and that serves as "allocation" for any static data in that shared object.

When `foo.so` is unloaded, the data (and code) is disposed of via `munmap` system call.

> I assume this takes place in the _init() and _fini() functions

That assumption is not correct. The `_init` and `_fini` are about *dynamic* initialization (e.g. global variables of class type in `C++` with a non-trivial constructor/destructor). By the time `_init` is called, the memory for all globals has already been "reserved" via `mmap`.

> However does the BSS segment

The `.bss` section is included in the same `PT_LOAD` segment in which other initialized (writable) data is. This is why there is a separate `p_filesz` and `p_memsz` in the `ElfXX_Phdr`: the `p_filesz` "covers" initialized data, and (larger) `p_memsz` causes the `mmap` to "allocate" space for both initialized and `.bss` data.

> What about global data in a dynamic module?

What about it? I covered initialized data above.

> Would there be possibility of symbol name clashes with the primary executable?

Certainly. You can define `int foo = 42;` in `a.out`, and `int foo = 24;` in `foo.so`. The usual rule is that *if* `foo` is visible in the dynamic symbol table of `a.out`, then that `foo` will be used regardless of where it is referenced from.

Complications arise when `a.out` does not export `foo` (if it is not linked with `-rdymamic` *and* does not link against `foo.so`), or when `foo.so` is linked with `-Bsymbolic`.

Comment: Thanks @EmployedRussian, I dug a bit more on the dynamic symbol table, it seems that the global symbols are only exported to the dynamic symbol table when -rdynamic is specified.  It appears normally they are not exported so the dynamic module cannot access those from the executable.   Is this correct?

Comment: @DKWH There are 3 ways (that I know of) for a symbol to be exported from a.out: (1) you link with `-rdynamic` (or `-E`, or `--export-dynamic`) or (2) you directly link with `foo.so`   that uses the symbol or (3) you export the symbol in a linker version script.